# How is ください　used?

Tags: expressions

I was wondering how I would use kudasai.
Could I use it for asking for items (私はこれがほしいですください）or for a polite, almost English 'Can you let me sit here please'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ください cannot be used as a direct replacement for the English word 'please'.

It is the imperative form of くださる which is the honorofic version of くれる meaning 'to give'.

It can be used directly with nouns e.g.:

> これをください
>   Please give me this

It can also attach to the te-form of verbs with the meaning "please do verb for me" e.g.:

> コーヒーを買ってください
>   Please buy me a coffee