# Use of ともちょうだい and speaker consistency

Tags: giving-and-receiving

> [チケットが二枚余ってて～とかいってくる男がいたから、いらないなら２枚ともちょうだいって言っただけ](https://kuragebunch.com/episode/10834108156633686051)
>
> it's cuz there's a guy that said he had 2 extra tickets, "if they aren't needed, i'll accept them" is all I said.

The latter half is the speaker talking about her own remarks right? Is there a more exact way to pinpoint that other than deducing from context? (ie, only girls use ちょうだい)

is there distinction between ～てちょうだい　and ～ともちょうだい？

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「チケットが2枚余ってて～」とか言ってくる男がいたから、「いらないなら2枚ともちょうだい」って言っただけ
>   There was a guy who said to me something like "I have two extra tickets", so I just said "If you don't need them, give me both."
>
> (brackets added by me)

ちょうだい is used regardless of sex, and there is no personal pronoun, so you have to determine the subject of 言った at the end only form the context.

ちょうだい following a te-form is "please ～ (for me)", but in this case ちょうだい means "give me." (ください works very similarly. See [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42741/5010).)

とも is a suffix that mainly follows an adverb made of a number and a counter. It means "all/both of the ～". See [this](https://j-nihongo.com/tomoall/).

Examples:

- このチケットを見てちょうだい。 Take a look at this ticket.
- チケット(を)ちょうだい。 Give me a ticket. / Give me some tickets.
- 2枚ちょうだい。 (You have many tickets) Give me two.
- 2枚ともちょうだい。 (You have two tickets) Give me both of the two.
- 3枚ともちょうだい。 (You have three tickets) Give me all of the three.
- 2回成功した。 I succeeded twice (in several trials).
- 2回とも成功した。 I succeeded in both of the two trials.